# Order in while loop when using hasNextInt statement

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, user-input

I'm just starting out with java. I'm trying to write a code that adds numbers to an ArrayList using user input. I found a way to run a while loop that stops when I input anything but a number, using a 'hasNextInt' statement, but for some reason it goes straight for the input and only then prints out the message from the first if statement. What am I doing wrong?

Output looks like this:

`This program takes grades from 1 to 100
    You may begin typing numbers now
    To stop setting grades, type any word (like 'done') 
    Enter the 1st number:
    68
    54
    Enter the 2nd number
    94
    Enter the 3rd number`

This is the code I wrote:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> myClassroom = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    GradeAnalyzer myAnalyzer = new GradeAnalyzer();
    System.out.println("This program takes grades from 1 to 100");
    System.out.println("You may begin typing numbers now");
    System.out.println("To stop setting grades, type any word (like 'done') ");
    int counter = 1;
    System.out.println("Enter the 1st number:");
    while(input.hasNextInt()) {
        if (counter == 21 || counter == 31 || counter == 41 || counter == 51 || counter == 61) {
            System.out.println("Enter the " + counter + "st" + " number");
        } else if (counter == 2 ||counter == 22 ||counter == 32 ||counter == 42 ||counter == 52 ||counter == 62) {
            System.out.println("Enter the " + counter + "nd" + " number");
        } else if (counter == 3 ||counter == 23 ||counter == 33 ||counter == 43 ||counter == 53 ||counter == 63){
            System.out.println("Enter the " + counter + "rd" + " number");
        } else if (counter == 1) {
            System.out.print("");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter the " + counter + "th" + " number");
        }
        int cijfer = input.nextInt();
        if(cijfer < 0 || cijfer > 100) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 100.");
        } else {
            myClassroom.add(cijfer);
            counter++;
        }
    }  
    System.out.println("You entered " + counter + " valid numbers.");
}
```

Comment: hasNextInt() blocks until it knows if there is a next Int or not. It can't return anything until you have typed your second number. Note how, for the first number, you print the message, then you call hasNextInt(). For the second number, you do the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `hasNextInt` method will block until you enter input. When you reach `int cijfer = input.nextInt();`, the scanner will immediately fetch the number you wrote, and add it to the list. The loop will then call `input.hasNextInt()` again, which will ask for another number *before* printing your text.

To fix it, you can move the code getting the input to the top of your loop. Like this:

```
while(input.hasNextInt()) {
    int cijfer = input.nextInt();
    if(cijfer < 0 || cijfer > 100) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 100.");
    } else {
        myClassroom.add(cijfer);
        counter++;
    }

    if(counter == 21 || counter == 31 || counter == 41 || counter == 51 || counter == 61) {
        System.out.println("Enter the " + counter + "st" + " number");
    } else if(counter == 2 ||counter == 22 ||counter == 32 ||counter == 42 ||counter == 52 ||counter == 62) {
        System.out.println("Enter the " + counter + "nd" + " number");
    } else if(counter == 3 ||counter == 23 ||counter == 33 ||counter == 43 ||counter == 53 ||counter == 63){
        System.out.println("Enter the " + counter + "rd" + " number");
    } else if(counter == 1) {
        System.out.print("");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Enter the " + counter + "th" + " number");
    }
}
```

PS. The `counter` variable will be one off when you exit the loop here. You can fix that yourself ;)

Comment: @Broeskoenoe Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you ;)

Comment: Didn't know it worked that way, I accepted the answer!